# Prioritise query values over others using another query for values to be prioritised

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following query of Olympic countries in power query which I wish to sort using another query containing "prioritised countries" (the current top 10). I wish to sort the original query such that if a country is on the prioritised list it is alphabetically sorted at the top of the query.

Below visually shows what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The best I have been able to do is merge queries however this removes countries not on the prioritised query. I appreciate that I can create a second query of the original, append this to the prioritised countries and then remove duplicates however I am looking for a more elegant solution as this will require refreshing the data twice.

Answer (score 1):

Let `Q` be the query to sort and `P` be the priority list. Then you can get your desired result by appending the intersection `Q ∩ P` with the set difference `Q \ P`.

[image: Venn Diagrams]

Here's one way to do this in M:

```
let
    Source =
    Table.FromList(
        List.Combine(
            {
                List.Sort( List.Intersect( { P[Country], Q[Country] } ) ),
                List.Sort( List.RemoveItems( Q[Country], P[Country] ) )
            }
        ),
        null,
        {"Country"}
    )
in
    Source
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, Ive actually realised I have misunderstood how the merge function in power query can work. Simply using merge with left outer as the join kind still retains all values, when expanding this the data is sorted as required. Apologies but thanks anyway!